# Как правильно разбить ячейки в ListView?

Tags: java, listview, javafx

Доброго времени дня!
Не могу разбить ячейки в ListView , что бы отображало картинку ,кнопку и текст на одной строке.Попытался , но не получилось весь вечер решить не могу.Спасибо

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import sample.objects.CollectionContactForList;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("views/sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 300));

    primaryStage.show();
}
private void testData(){
    CollectionContactForList contactForList= new CollectionContactForList();

    contactForList.fieldData();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
 }
}
```

Класс Контроллер для обработки

```
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import sample.objects.CollectionContactForList;
import sample.objects.Contact;
 public class Controller {
 //Коллекции
 CollectionContactForList contactForList = new CollectionContactForList();

 @FXML
 HBox hbox;

 @FXML
 ListView<Contact> listContact;
 @FXML
 Label name;

 public  void setListView(){

    listContact.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Contact>, ListCell<Contact>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<Contact> call(ListView<Contact> param) {
            //тут нужно собрать объект ListCell, и вернуть его
            ListCell<Contact> listCell = new ListCell<Contact>(){
                //обрисовка происходит здесь
                @Override
                public void updateItem(Contact item , boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    if (empty || item == null) {

                    } else {
                        HBox hBox = new HBox();
                        name.setText("");
                        ImageView.class.getResourceAsStream("/resurse/logo.png");
                        // Тут нужно загрузить xml
                        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("boxInContact.fxml"));
                        //устанавливаем графику
                       // setGraphic();

                    }
                }
            };
            return   listCell;

        }
    });

}

     @FXML
     private void initialize() {
    /*
      listContact.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Contact>,             ListCell<Contact>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<Contact> call(ListView<Contact> param) {
            //тут нужно собрать объект ListCell, и вернуть его
            ListCell<Contact> listCell = new ListCell<Contact>(){
                //отрисовка происходит здеся
                @Override
                public void updateItem(Contact item , boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    if (empty || item == null) {

                    } else {
                        HBox hBox = new HBox();
                        name.setText("");
                        ImageView.class.getResourceAsStream("/resurse/logo.png");
                        // Тут нужно загрузить xml
                        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("boxInContact.fxml"));
                        //устанавливаем графику
                        // setGraphic();
                    }
                }
            };
            return   listCell;
        }
    });
   */
          contactForList.fieldData();
          listContact.setItems((ObservableList<Contact>)  contactForList.getContactList());
      //setListView();
}

 }//Закрытие класса
```

Класс Контакт , вот его и нужно отобразить

```
    public class Contact {
    ImageView imageView;
    private String avatar = "/logo.png";
    private String name;
    Button button;

public Contact(String avatar, String name, Button button) {
    this.avatar = avatar;
    this.name = name;
    this.button = button;
}

public String getAvatar() {
    return avatar;
}

public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
    this.avatar = avatar;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Button getButton() {
    return button;
}

public void setButton(Button button) {
    this.button = button;
}



}
```

Класс , содержащий коллекцию Контактов

```
  public class CollectionContactForList implements ForContact {

   public ObservableList<Contact> contactList=  FXCollections.observableArrayList();
//Set<Contact>setContactList = new HashSet<>();
  public   ListView<Contact> listView = new ListView<Contact> ((ObservableList<Contact>) contactList);



// Методы интерфейса

@Override
public void add(Contact contact) {
    contactList.add(contact);
}// Закрытие метода добавления

@Override
public void update(Contact contact) {

}// метод ,пока не используется , вскорем будущем применим его 15 04

@Override
public void delete(Contact contact) {
    contactList.remove(contact);
}// Закрытие метода удаления

   public List<Contact> getContactList() {
    return contactList;
  }


   public void fieldData(){
   contactList.add( new Contact("","ada",new Button("st")));

  }

 }// Закрытие класса
```

Сам GUI

```
?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>


 <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-I   nfinity"      minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"   xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"  fx:controller="sample.controllers.Controller">
      <children>
      <BorderPane layoutX="164.0" layoutY="79.0" prefHeight="400.0"  prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
      <left>
        <TabPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0"  tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
          <tabs>
            <Tab fx:id="tabContact" text="Untitled Tab 1">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                       <children>
                          <ListView fx:id="listContact" layoutX="-31.0" layoutY="43.0" prefHeight="371.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                       </children>
                    </AnchorPane>
              </content>
            </Tab>
            <Tab text="Untitled Tab 2">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                       <children>
                          <ListView layoutX="14.0" layoutY="75.0" p  refHeight="371.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0"   AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0"   AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                       </children>
                    </AnchorPane>
                  </content>
                 </Tab>
                  </tabs>
                </TabPane>
              </left>
             <top>
          <ListView fx:id="listUser" prefHeight="58.0" prefWidth="600.0"       BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
        </top>
       </BorderPane>
       </children>
     </AnchorPane>
```

А этот fxml файл нужен для загрузки его в ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<HBox fx:id="hbox" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="- Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="99.0" prefWidth="139.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"  fx:controller="sample.controllers.Controller">
 <children>
  <ImageView fitHeight="98.0" fitWidth="67.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" fx:id="image"/>
     <Label prefHeight="98.0" prefWidth="45.0" text="Label" fx:id="name"/>
      <Button fx:id="btnStatus" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button"  />
   </children>
</HBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь [Scene Builder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html), сократит время разработки интерфейса программы в разы.

Comment: а разве в нем можно обернуть контроллеры  в ListView , допустим Hbox внутри которого Label ,Button ?

Comment: Не могу дать 100% ответ на Ваш вопрос, попробуйте.